# Pass one attribute three times in a json array in a json serializable object in java

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I am trying to duplicate the following JSON Payload using a Java serializable object.

```
{
    "startDate": "2022-09-11",
    "endDate": "9999-12-31",
    "columns": [
        {
            "attribute": "FTOS"
        },
        {
            "attribute": "StartDate"
        },
        {
            "attribute": "EndDate"
        }
    ],
    "ids": [
        {
            "id": "EAY9",
            "idType": "InvestmentId"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the POJO and code I am trying.

```
public class Column{
    public String attribute;
}

public class Id{
    public String id;
    public String idType;
}

public class Root{
    public String startDate;
    public String endDate;
    public ArrayList<Column> columns;
    public ArrayList<Id> ids;
}
```

The issue is while setting the attribute. If you see in the payload, we have it repeated three times whereas I am trying to set that in the following manner to replicate the same but I am getting only a single attribute in my payload. Below is the code.

```
Column col=new Column();
    List<Column> colList=new ArrayList<>();
    
    col.setAttribute("FTOS");
    col.setAttribute("StartDate");
    col.setAttribute("EndDate");
    colList.add(col);
```

But I am getting the following payload in the actual output.

```
{
    "startDate": "2022-09-11",
    "endDate": "9999-12-31",
    "columns": [
        {
            "attribute": "EndDate"
        }
    ],
    "ids": [
        {
            "id": "EAY9",
            "idType": "InvestmentId"
        }
    ]
}
```

The attribute you see is displayed only once. How to generate it three times as in the expected payload?

Comment: you need 3 objects of columns you only have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Anon indicated in the comments: "you need 3 objects of columns you only have one –
Anon"
Create a new `Column` object for each attribute you need to add to the list:

```
List<Column> colList=new ArrayList<>();
Column col1=new Column();
col1.setAttribute("FTOS");
colList.add(col1);
Column col2=new Column();
col2.setAttribute("StartDate");
colList.add(col2);
Column col3=new Column();
col3.setAttribute("EndDate");
colList.add(col3);
```